# Excel VBA - Looking for Strings in "Text Block" , then look in the next

Tags: vba, excel

I doesnt find a solution for my problem in the WWW.
Hope you can help me:

I've imported a long text file with various information: it looks like this:

```
id 5
name node1
UPS_serial_number
WWNN 500507680350BD
status online
IO_group_id 0
IO_group_name io_grp0
partner_node_id 4
partner_node_name node2
config_node yes
UPS_unique_id
port_id 500507680456454
port_status active
port_speed 8Gb
port_id 500507680545644
port_status active
port_speed 8Gb

id 4
name node2
UPS_serial_number
WWNN 500507680200DDE8
status online
IO_group_id 0
IO_group_name io_grp0
partner_node_id 4
partner_node_name node1
config_node yes
UPS_unique_id
port_id 5005076803594BDE
port_status active
port_speed 8Gb
port_id 500507680235486F
port_status active
port_speed 8Gb

.
.
.
```

Its almost formatted in the right format like this:
[string || value]

I want to look in the first block and get the infos for name, id, WWPN - then copy the values to another worksheet.
Then look into the second block and get the same infos: name, id, WWPN and copy them.

Then next block and the next block and so on.

I have the following code:

```
Sub find_test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim tRow
LR = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LR)

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells

tRow = rngCell.Row
 If StrComp(rngCell.Value, "name") = 0 Then                                      'Node 1 Service IP
        Worksheets("temp").Range("E16").Value = Worksheets("lsnodecanister").Range("B" & tRow).Value
     End If
     Next


End Sub
```

The Text blocks are almost seperated by an empty row.

Do you have any idea? 
Hope it was understandable.

Thank you very much,

Best regards,
Kalain

Comment: `Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlup).Row` and `split` function will assist.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I doesnt work with split yet. But I thinks I dont need this function. The Text is already splitted in Column A and B. Or is it a missunterstanding?

Comment: sorry, I understand now :)  you need to wrap this up in another loop, so something like `do until range("a" & lr+1).value=""`, then retain the `LR = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row`, but change to `LR = Cells(LR, 1).End(xlDown).Row`  I'll mock an answer up

Comment: Does each block have the exact same number of lines, and are the names on the left always the same?  If so then you can use the split function on the space " " as @Kalain suggested to separate the names from the value and put them into  two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
Sub SO1()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRowOfSection As Long
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim strName As String

lngRow = 1

Do Until Cells(lngRow + 1, 1).Value = ""

    lngLastRowOfSection = Cells(lngRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Set rngFind = Range(Cells(lngRow, 1), Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1)).Find("name")
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        strName = rngFind.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Debug.Print strName
    End If

    lngRow = Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    If lngRow >= Rows.Count Then Exit Do

Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood the question.  I think you meant that each line of your data has the name and data separated by a space.  I manipulated your subroutine to put all values in column a into an array and then I split the array into columns B and C.

```
Sub find_test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim tRow As Long
Dim myArray() As Variant, arrayCounter As Long
Dim lilStringArray
'

    LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim myArray(1 To 1)
    arrayCounter = 1
    myArray = Range("A1:A" & LR)
    tRow = 1
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If myArray(i, 1) <> "" Then
            lilStringArray = Split(myArray(i, 1), " ")
            Range("B" & tRow).Value = lilStringArray(0)
            On Error Resume Next
                Range("C" & tRow).Value = lilStringArray(1)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
             Range("C" & tRow).Value = ""
        End If
        tRow = tRow + 1
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: It seems as though you re-programmed here the `text-to-columns" button in Excel.

Comment: Well, yes.  I didn't think about that.  I know he wants to put the data on another worksheet.  What I did here was give him the logic - not the code he needs to accomplish his end goal.  He can replace the last "for i" loop to accommodate his actual needs.  The thing is that he now has the data in an array that he can split in any way he needs.